# How can I put text in column form inside node of a Tree using TikZ Picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees, tikz-node

Hi pretend make a simple tree with TikZ, where each node has a simple math text
with several lines, in columns.

Here my LaTex but I don't know why each line of the text doesn't
put one under the other one?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
[
  normal/.style={circle,draw,solid,scale=0.3}
]

\node[normal]{
$\quad A \in \langle $$\color{blue}9$$ \rangle$
$\quad B \in \langle $$\color{blue}4 \dots 7$$ \rangle$
$\quad C \in \langle $$\color{blue}5 \dots 8$$ \rangle$
$\quad D \in \langle $$\color{blue}2 \dots 8$$ \rangle$
$\quad E \in \langle $$\color{blue}1$$ \rangle$
$\quad F \in \langle $$\color{blue}0$$ \rangle$
$\quad G \in \langle $$\color{blue}2 \dots 8$$ \rangle$
$\quad H \in \langle $$\color{blue}2 \dots 8$$ \rangle$

}
    child { node[normal] {a} }
    child { node[normal] {b} };


\end{tikzpicture}
```

regards

Comment: Please provide complete code which people can compile to reproduce the problem. Don't make people guess - it is a lot more hassle and makes it less likely answers will actually help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not tell it to break the line inside the node. One way is to use an `aligned` environment from `amsmath`. Is it something like this you are looking for?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
[
  normal/.style={circle,draw,solid,scale=0.3}
]
\node[normal]{$
  \begin{aligned}
    \quad A &\in \langle {\color{blue}9} \rangle\\
    \quad B &\in \langle {\color{blue}4 \dots 7} \rangle\\
    \quad C &\in \langle {\color{blue}5 \dots 8} \rangle\\
    \quad D &\in \langle {\color{blue}2 \dots 8} \rangle\\
    \quad E &\in \langle {\color{blue}1} \rangle\\
    \quad F &\in \langle {\color{blue}0} \rangle\\
    \quad G &\in \langle {\color{blue}2 \dots 8} \rangle\\
    \quad H &\in \langle {\color{blue}2 \dots 8} \rangle    
  \end{aligned}$}
    child { node[normal] {a} }
    child { node[normal] {b} };
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]